# A Service Loaded exe can't 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start' a URL?

Tags: c#, windows-services, system-tray

I have a simple Tray icon program that opens a site using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("URL")
```

And it works fine independently, however when a service loads it, it gives a file not found exception when trying to open the URL, and after testing it can open normal extensions, e.g `.txt` (The service has desktop interaction enabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Process.Start a URL, it is loading a browser app, which isn't (for Vista/etc) going to display for a service (for the same reasons as your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355579)).

If you want the app to interact with the user/desktop, it shouldn't be a service - it should simply run when the user logs in. Note that any child-process that your service spawns will *also* be in the service's session.

If you just want to get data (through code) from the site, use `WebClient` etc.